# SeekBarPreferences.setOnSeekBarChangeListener

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want do something like

```
(mySeekBarPreferences as SeekBar).setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : 
            SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener { 
        override fun onProgressChanged(seek: SeekBar, 
              progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) { 
          // write custom code for progress is changed 
        }
```

But i can't cast my seekbarpreferences as seekbar so i can't do this method, then i tried :

```
(mySeekBarPreferences as SeekBarPreference).setOnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
                    // write custom code for progress is changed
                    true
                }
```

But that doesn't work cause i need to click around the bar on the view to be listen by the OnPreferenceChangeListener, so my question is, how can i have the same result than the first method but with SeekBarPreference and not a seekbar ?

Thanks

EDIT : The issues was finally to add `app:updatesContinuously="true"` in the XML file. That detect continously the update of the value while the drag.

Comment: "i need to click around the bar on the view to be listen by the OnPreferenceChangeListener" Can you clarify what you mean, because this looks like the proper way to do this.

Comment: Yes that's true, it wasn't the problem way finally